# Insert output of stored procedure into temp table along with parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I want to insert the output of a stored procedure and along parameter value into a temp table.

Issue = If I have 3 records, then am getting 1st id repeating 3 times, 2nd id repeating 2 times and 3rd id repeating 1 time. What would be the issue?

Here is the code I tried.

```
DECLARE @param INT
DECLARE @tempable TABLE 
                  (
                       fname varchar(10), 
                       lname varchar(10), 
                       city varchar(10), 
                       country varchar(10)
                  )
DECLARE @tempable1 TABLE 
                   (
                        fname varchar(10), 
                        lname varchar(10), 
                        city varchar(10), 
                        country varchar(10), 
                        id int
                   )

DECLARE curs CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT distinct empid 
    FROM emp

OPEN curs
FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @param

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @temtable
        EXEC dbo.employeedata NULL, NULL, @param, NULL, NULL

    SELECT * FROM @temptable

    FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @param
END

CLOSE curs
DEALLOCATE curs

INSERT INTO @tempable1 (fname, lname, city, country, id)
    SELECT fname, lname, city, country, @param  
    FROM @temptable

SELECT * FROM @tempable1
```

Comment: `tempable1` doesn't have an `id` column defined, yet you are inserting an `id`? Secondly the `id` you are inserting is `@param` which will always have the same value (last) outside the loop. Sample data and desired results would clarify because I don't really know what you are trying to do here. I guess you are just trying to add `@param` to the results, but why not do that in your SP?

Comment: Thanks, while adding code here, i forgot to add 'id' in 'tempable1'. Problem here, i can't modify SP. I have to use SP as is. Unfortunately, SP doesn't return 'id' value.

Comment: You could do this by adding an identity column to your temp table, using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to capture the value in the row just inserted, then update that row.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid does that work with `INSERT INTO EXEC`? I thought the table definition had to exactly match.

Comment: Actually yeah you’re right.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in one temp table, perform an `update ... where ... is null` after `insert into ..exec`

```
DECLARE @param INT

DECLARE @tempable1 TABLE 
(
    fname varchar(10), 
    lname varchar(10)), 
    city varchar(10), 
    country varchar(10), 
    id int
)

DECLARE curs CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT distinct empid FROM emp

OPEN curs
FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @param

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    -- change to @temtable1 and specify the column name explicityly
    INSERT INTO @temtable1 (fname, lname, city, country)
    EXEC dbo.employeedata null, null, @param, null, null

    -- update id column with @parm where id is null
    UPDATE @temptable1
    SET    id = @param
    WHERE  id IS NULL

    FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @param
END

CLOSE curs
DEALLOCATE curs
    
SELECT * FROM @tempable1
```

Comment: Is that possible? I didn't think you could specify the columns when using `INSERT INTO EXEC`

Comment: Yes. see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=24a0e5e226998968442dc92c081fa37b)

Comment: Awesome! I never knew that...

Comment: Works on both temp table and table variable

Answer (score 2):

It is an annoying problem when you use `INSERT INTO` with `EXEC` and want additional columns. I think the solution here is to move the rows to the new table in the loop, then delete them from the first table to avoid duplicates. See below:

```
DECLARE @param INT;
DECLARE @tempable TABLE (fname varchar(10), lname varchar(10)), city varchar(10), country varchar(10));
DECLARE @tempable1 TABLE (fname varchar(10), lname varchar(10)), city varchar(10), country varchar(10), id int);

DECLARE curs CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT distinct empid FROM emp;

OPEN curs;
FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @param;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @temtable
    EXEC dbo.employeedata null, null, @param, null, null;

    -- SELECT * FROM @temptable;

    INSERT INTO @tempable1 (fname, lname, city, country, id)
        SELECT fname, lname, city, country, @param
        FROM @temptable;

    DELETE FROM @temptable;

    FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @param;
END;

CLOSE curs;
DEALLOCATE curs;

SELECT * FROM @tempable1;
```

Note that SQL statements should now be `;` terminated.

Comment: Super Dale. Thanks it works.